How to customize Javers comparison for generic field
I have a problem with Javers thinking a commit contains changes, however it should be empty. The cause is that an enum is stored as string in the database, and when comparing the latest snapshot from DB with the new value, a string is compared with an enum value.
The reason for Javers not converting the database string value into the enum value is that the property is a generic field. I created a test case for this. This is my example entity:
@Document("test-entity")
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    public ObjectId id;

    public TestGeneric<TestEnum> testData;

}

and the corresponding test generic class:
public class TestGeneric<T> {

    public T data;

}

and the corresponding test enum:
public enum TestEnum {
    A,
    B
}

I actually use Spring Boot 3.0.2 with the javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo 7.6.3.
To put all together, I have my repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<TestEntity, String> {
}

and, finally, a test service:
@Service
public class TestService {

    private final TestRepository testRepository;

    public TestService(TestRepository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TestEntity testEntity = testRepository.findOne(Example.of(new TestEntity())).orElse(new TestEntity());
        testEntity.testData = new TestGeneric<>();
        testEntity.testData.data = TestEnum.B;
        testRepository.save(testEntity);
        TestEntity testEntity2 = testRepository.findOne(Example.of(new TestEntity())).orElse(new TestEntity());
        testEntity2.testData = new TestGeneric<>();
        testEntity2.testData.data = TestEnum.B;
        testRepository.save(testEntity2);
    }

}

When it runs the first time, it will create a new document, something like this in the database:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "672cdf37f7fbc851d26d9e37"
  },
  "testData": {
    "data": "B"
  },
  "_class": "org.example.TestEntity"
}

and it will log:

Commit(id:11.00, snapshots:2, author:unknown, changes - NewObject:1 InitialValueChange:2), done in 40 ms (diff:21 ms, persist:19 ms)
Skipping persisting empty commit: Commit(id:12.00, snapshots:0, author:unknown, changes -)
Commit(id:12.00, snapshots:0, author:unknown, changes -), done in 1 ms (diff:1 ms, persist:0 ms)

It created one document and two commits. The first one had initial changes, the second one did not change anything. This is expected.
When running the same thing again (with a persistent database in use), the logs will be:

Commit(id:12.00, snapshots:1, author:unknown, changes - ValueChange:1), done in 41 ms (diff:31 ms, persist:10 ms)
Skipping persisting empty commit: Commit(id:14.00, snapshots:0, author:unknown, changes -)
Commit(id:14.00, snapshots:0, author:unknown, changes -), done in 1 ms (diff:1 ms, persist:0 ms)

This is not expected. The first commit is not ignored, because of my explanations at the beginning of this post. The second commit is ignored.
My question is: How do I tell Javers that the first commit is empty? I think I know how it should work, but I need help how to do it.
I think it should work by telling Javers to compare TestEnum fields by converting it to String first. Or, it should also work by telling Javers how to deserialize the String value from the DB, into a TestEnum value. I dont know how to do either of them. I already tried registering a Json TypeAdapter (BasicStringTypeAdapter) for TestEnum but it did not help.
Also, I find it interesting that the second commit is ignored. Something works different the second time. There might be a solution to this problem by investigating why the second commit is being ignored. But I was not able to find it out.
